# why the cookies continues working

Tags: sockets, http, cookies

I have a question about the reason the web applications continues setting cookies, because the persistent HTTP conections use sockets, i.e.: websocket.

HTTP 1.1 and 2 uses persistent http conections, with sockets in the client and server. These sockets are active a necessary time for loading a complete web page (HTML, CSS, images, etc), then the sockets are killed by the server. It is logic due to the server does not know what is doing the client. So, in this scenario, the use of the cookies is justified.

But, with websocket i think the scenary is different, because it uses only one socket, so it means that after the conection is done, the server and the client uses the sockets for sending data.

So, the question is... why are the cookies necessary if the server know who is the client?

Answer (score 0):

This question is impossibly broad, since many different web applications work in many different ways.

In general, cookies are used to store data that needs to persist beyond the momentary connection between the client and the server.

More specifically, the connection between the client and the server can be very transient. The server receives a request, sends a page, and moves on to the next request. It doesn't maintain a constant connection to every browser that contacts it.

Comment: Sure, i know that is right. Thanks for the response. But i'm trying to understand why the web servers works different that ssh for example, the ssh server creates a socket and the ssh client creates another socket, those sockets will be sending and receiving data until the client or the server close the connection. The ssh server can work with a lot of ssh clients too.